# How to disable keyboard button toggle light

Tags: keyboard, led, function-keys

I have an HP Envy 14, which features several smart function keys to mute sound / mute the microfone / disable the camera. When the function is toggled on, this is indicated by the little LED beneath the key turning on.

[image: example of toggle key]

I would like to find a way to disable not the function itself but the LED toggling on, not the background lighting but all button indicator LEDs (possibly without phsycically destroying said LED).

Specifically the power button features a LED that is always on when the computer is running and I'd rather not have a shiny light on permanently.

Is there a way through BIOS / drivers / settings to achieve this? I haven't found anything so far that wasn't related to problems with the actual function execution (eg. LED turned on permanently due to wrong microfone driver).

Thank you !

Comment: A little drop of correction fluid, such as Tipp-Ex?

Comment: elegant, simple, best solution here :-)
thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution : a little drop of correction fluid, such as Tipp-Ex,
avoids perilous hardware manipulations.

Comment: i would have and will, thank you !